# Magento 2 : How to Customise Admin Sales Order Grid Collection

Tags: admin, grid, sales-order, magento-2.1.3

I am trying to customise admin sale order grid collection.
I have created an custom `sale_order` attribute `store_manager`. These store managers are admin users eg: 'manager1', 'manager2'.

1) Orders are manually assigned to 'manager1' or 'manager2' -- **this part is done**

2) Now I am trying to set filter on sale order grid collection, so when manager logged in to there system they can only see there orders.

In Magento 1 we have `sales_order_grid_collection_load_before`, `sales_order_grid_collection_load_after` for this requirement .

Is tried to such event for Magento 2 but didn't get any success.

**My Queries :**

Is there any such event like (`sales_order_grid_collection_load_after`) in magento 1 which full fill my requirement?

Is there any other way where I can set filter to sale order grid collection?

Note : I already search for this on google but didn't get any perfect solution.

Comment: Any Solution about filter Order grid collection by admin user id?

Answer (score 0):

override with your module Mage_Sales by writing in module.xml smth like

```
<module name="----" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

Create in your module view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

in sales_order_grid do smth like

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<columns name="sales_order_columns">
    <column name="attribute_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Attribute Name</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">3</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom module or already exit its not issue.
In etc folder di.xml created plugin

```
        <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter">
                <plugin name="bindStoreManagerSearch" type="Namespace\Module_name\Plugin\Grid\Search\StoreManagerSearch" sortOrder="1" />
        </type>
```

Create StoreManagerSearch.php file in plugin folder

```
        <?php

            namespace Namespace\Module_name\Plugin\Grid\Search;

            class StoreManagerSearch {

                public function aroundApply(
                    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter $subject, 
                    callable $proceed, 
                    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection, 
                    \Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filter
                ){  
                    $result = $proceed($collection, $filter);

                    if($collection->getConnection()->tableColumnExists($collection->getMainTable(), 'store_manager')) {

                        $collection->getSelect()->orWhere('`main_table`.store_manager = ?', $filter->getValue()); 

                        $parentTable = null;

                        if($collection->getMainTable() == 'sales_order_grid') {

                            $parentTable = 'sales_order';

                        } else if($collection->getMainTable() == 'sales_invoice_grid') {

                            $parentTable = 'sales_invoice';

                        } else if($collection->getMainTable() == 'sales_shipment_grid') {

                            $parentTable = 'sales_shipment';

                        } else if($collection->getMainTable() == 'sales_creditmemo_grid') {

                            $parentTable = 'sales_creditmemo';
                        } else {

                            $parentTable = 'sales_order';
                        }

                        if($parentTable && $collection->getConnection()->tableColumnExists($parentTable, 'store_manager')) {

                            $collection->getSelect()->join(
                                ['sm' => $parentTable],
                                "sm.entity_id = main_table.entity_id",
                                []
                            ); 

                            $collection->getSelect()->orWhere('`sm`.store_manager = ?', $filter->getValue());  
                        } 
                    } 

                    return $result;
                }
            }
```